# Best way to organize junction table

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I'm currently building a small database on MS Access for upgrades (45) on several machines (30) on a factory. The info is on an excel spreadsheet where rows are the upgrades and columns the machine. The excel file shows how for each machine if a certain upgrade is already installed/to be installed/in dev/etc.

I currently have a table for each upgrade details and another table with every machine and its personal info.

To replicate the excel associations I intend on making a junction table.
Should I make it with the upgrades as a field (1 col) and the machine as another. That would give 3 columns and 30*45 rows.
Or should I imitate the excel and put the upgrades as a field and each machine as an individual field, the values being the state of the upgrade.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The spreadsheet could not maintain a history.  I'd create a Machine table and an Upgrade table.  The Upgrade table would have multiple rows for each Machine row, with the only difference (generally) being the upgrade timestamp.  You could have different upgrades for a particular machine.  If so, you'd need an UpgradeType table to distinguish the upgrade types.

Comment: as Arturo said in his answer a simple Many to Many model looks like the best approach given the information you have provided.  use Many to Many and Access as your keyword and watch some youtube videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A junction table is typically used to build a many-to-many relationship. From what you describe, it seems to be the case that you have. The fields of the junction Table must include the Key field(s) of the two Tables between which you want to establish a many-to-many relationship. In your case, it seems that the junction table should have the key field(s) of table "machines" and the key field(s) of table "upgrades". You then build a one-to-many relationship with referential integrity from the table "machines", over the key fields, to the corresponding fields in the junction table. You do the same from the key field(s) of the table "upgrades" to the corresponding fields of the junction table. Then you populate the junction table with the corresponding data. It is quite frequent to include additional fields inthe junction table to provide useful information, like having a date field to record on what date each upgrade was done for each specific machine, or a comments fields, or the person that did the upgrade.

If you want to see a concrete example, you can take a look to the juntion Table "T_Umbrellas_in_Capitals" from the database of examples that you can download from [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net). This junction table supports a many-to-many relationship  between the tables "T_Capital_cities" and "T_Umbrella_models".